# Чем отличаются ссылка или тип слева от равно от того что справа (при инициализации экземпляра объекта)?

Tags: java, классы

Допустим дан простейший пример:

```
Cat b = new Dog();
```

b - Это экземпляр того что слева, класса кат или дог?

А Вот посложнее:

```
Collection d = new ArrayList<>();
```

d - это экземпляр класса ArrayList, а причём тогда Collection? И чем тогда будет отличаться от:

```
ArrayList d = new ArrayList<>();
```

Если слева это просто ссылка типа ArrayList (как мы делаем к примеру Cat cat, где cat ссылка на класс Cat), то какой смысл вообще ставить слева (слово ArrayList) если то что справа главнее? )

Так ведь тип, который справа переходит экземпляру типа того что слева, так получается.

Answer (score 3):

```
Cat b = new Dog();
```

Не скомпилируется, если Dog не наследуется от Cat. Если же наследуется, то в программе явно нестандартная теория эволюции используется.

В переменной всегда окажется то, что вы в неё запишите, т.е. то, что идёт справа от `=`.

Указывают же супер-тип или интерфейс для удобства обычно. Также это общепринятое соглашение - указывать минимально подходящий тип при объявлении переменной. Делается это по нескольким причинам:

1. Чтобы случайно не получить доступ к ненужным методам класса. Если у переменной вы будете вызывать только методы супер-класса, то вам не нужно иметь доступ к методам класса-наследника.
2. Возможно, вам захочется потом в переменную положить другого наследника супер-класса. Если вы не укажите их общий тип при объявлении переменной - у вас это не получится - компилятор будет ругаться.

Comment: Я понимаю, я имею ввиду когда левая и правая части связаны. Рассматриваем вариант когда всё прекрасно компилируется. То есть вы подтверждаете, что правая часть всегда передаётся в переменную. Пример я просто придумал :) А так, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @МихаилНевский, да, всё верно. В переменной в итоге будет экземпляр именно того класса, который находится справа от `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим ваш пример с Collection:

```
Collection col = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Действительно, переменная col объявлена как Collection, но указывает на ArrayList. Это означает, что вы можете на этой переменной вызывать только те методы, которые есть у Collection, игнорируя специфику ArrayList.

Конкретно, вы **не** можете выполнить метод col.sort(...), хотя реально у вас ArrayList, который этот метод поддерживает. А вот arr.sort(...) -- пожалуйста.

Итак, то, что слева, -- это тип переменной, он определяет, какие методы можно вызывать на этой переменной и что чему можно присваивать (при передаче параметров, например). То, что справа, -- это реальные объекты в хипе.

Ситуация, когда что-то общее ссылается на что-то более специфичное -- нормальна. Например, у вас есть метод, который принимает в качестве параметра коллекции. Любые коллекции. Например, так:

```
public static void printCollection(Collection col) {
    for (Object o : col) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Посмотрите, как интересно, мы можем передать ему хоть ArrayList, хоть LinkedList, хоть HashSet, хоть (не приведи господи) PriorityQueue. И он нормально отработает.

Вот какая ему разница, какую коллекцию ему передали?! Главное, что это Collection, а значит там есть метод `Iterator<T> iterator();` (а у всех подтипов Collection он есть). А значит параметр можно пролистать в цикле for.

Собственно для этого все эти штуки и придуманы.